# Best way to create a 2" wide * 6" deep channel in conrete

Tags: concrete, cutting

I'm looking to run a PVC pipe from my new laundry room to the garage where the house main sewer pipe lies. How would a pro do it? I'm assuming a concrete saw and hammer drill will be in play....

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Cut both sides of the channel with the concrete saw and break and clear out the concrete between the cuts using a jackhammer with a wide chisel bit, don't mess around with a hammer drill.  Both tools are readily available at most tool rental places and should make relatively fast work of these cuts.  Make sure you get a saw that can do the depth of cut that you want.

If you are a little more adventurous and or experienced with a jackhammer you could do a shallower cut or skip the concrete saw altogether.  It won't make as clean of an edge, but will be much faster, and depending on your circumstances it can be good enough and be covered when pouring the new concrete to refill the trench.

You'll want to do a wet cut with the saw to keep the dust down and cool the blade.

Depending on the amount of rebar you are anticipating you may want an abrasive blade (better for rebar) rather than a normal diamond concrete cutting blade (will cut rebar but will wear down the blade if cutting a lot of it).  Depending on the rental place you may need to buy your own blade.

You might also want to consider making the cut wider than 2".  This will give you room to work if you need to make up joints or otherwise manipulate the pipe and will also allow you to put some horizontal rebar into the remaining concrete (this is where you use the hammer drill) to better tie your new concrete back into the existing structure.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP would prefer not cutting the 6" trench all the way through the slab; any suggestions on how to control the depth? Perhaps doing multiple 6" deep cuts with the saw?

Comment: This answer seems right on. We just did something very similar. The op didn't mention trench length I don't think, but if it's short a concrete saw alone might be fine. You could use a sledgehammer and/or cross cuts to get the pieces broken out. A concrete saw is not too hard to use and that could save on rental costs. But it can be slow going.